# In TensorFlow, what happens to a shared variable if get_variable is called within map_fn

Tags: while-loop, tensorflow

I am trying to replace a for loop with map_fn, since the latter seems to help improving the loop efficiency.

The question is that, if the fn in map_fn calls get_variable() to create a new variable, how can I set reuse to True for the rest of the loop? Or is the get_variable() only called once in map_fn?

```
def fn(x):
     y = tf.get_variable('y', [])
     return x * x

squares = tf.map_fn(fn, np.array([1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6]))

# Out: [array([ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36])]
sess.run([squares])
```

Comment: `tf.all_variables()` only shows one variable so it looks like it only gets called once

Comment: Thank you @YaroslavBulatov ! I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: def fn(x):                                           
            y = tf.get_variable('y', [])
            print(y.name)
            return x * x
In [4]: import numpy as np
In [5]: squares = tf.map_fn(fn, np.array([1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6]))
y:0
```

As we can see that if a print is inserted in the fn and when it is called it prints only once.